# Find a vector that is not in the subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a matrix given by
$$
\mathbf{A}= \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 1&-1&0\\ 2&-1&1
\\ 3&-1&2\\ 0&1&a\end {array}
 \right] 
$$
The reduced form of $\mathbf{A}$ is
$$
\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 1&0&1\\ 0&1&1
\\ 0&0&a-1\\ 0&0&0\end {array}
 \right] 
$$
meaning that the column space of $\mathbf{A}$ is 3-dimensional(3 vectors in its basis). From what I have learnt, a set of $k$ linearly independent vectors is automatically a basis for the subspace $\mathbb{R}^k$. Thus since there are 3 vectors in the basis for the column space of $\mathbf{A}$, col $\mathbf{A}$ = $\mathbb{R}^3$(can someone confirm, I am not sure). Then, I am asked for find a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that is not in col $\mathbf{A}$, is this even possible?

Comment: Its the vector $(0,0,0,1)^T$ not lying in the span of the columns of A.

Comment: What is the reason for that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are wrong. The columns of $A$ belong to $\Bbb R^4$, not in $\Bbb R^3$. So, $\operatorname{col}\mathbf A$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^4$. Since it is a subspace of $\Bbb R^4$ spanned by a set of $3$ vectors, $\operatorname{col}\mathbf A\ne\Bbb R^4$.

Comment: But there are 3 vectors in the basis for col A - doesn't this mean that the basis spans R^3? See this https://math.stackexchange.com/q/978327/669308

Comment: They don't even *belong* to $\Bbb R^3$. How can the possibly span it?

Comment: @Dip $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\mathbb{R}^4$ are completely different vector spaces, for example, you cannot say $(1,1,1,1)\ \epsilon\  \mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Yes, but how does that conform with the answers given in the question I linked?

Comment: Ohh, wait @JoséCarlosSantos So if the column vectors in $\mathbf{A}$ would have been in $\mathbb{R}^3$, would my claim then have been true? That "since there are 3 vectors in the basis for the column space of $\mathbf{A}$, col $\mathbf{A}$ = $\mathbb{R}^3$"

Comment: Almost. Whenever $3$ vectors in $\Bbb R^3$ span the whole $\Bbb R^3$, they are a basis of $\mathbb R^3$.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you reduce the original matrix by column operations if you want to determine the independence of the column vectors, because then the columns of the reduced matrix will have the same span.

Provided $a \neq 1$ this gives a reduced form,

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 2 & a & -1 \\ 1 & 1+a & -1 \\ 0 & 2+a & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}. $$

If $a = -2$ the space has three dimensions, otherwise only two dimensions. Then create a vector that is orthogonal to all three columns to find a member of $\mathbf R ^4$ not in the columns space, for example $(1,-2,1,0)^T$. As it happens, this works for any $a $ including $a =1$.

For the case $a=1$, The reduced matrix has the form

$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 &  -1 \\0&2&-1\\0&3&-1\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix} $$ and $(1,-2,1,0)^T$ is still orthogonal to each column so not in the column space.  In this case, there will be a second independent vector also not in the column space.

PS. For $a\neq 1 $, we can see that $(0,0,0,1)^T = \frac{1}{1-a} \Big( \mathbf c_1 + \mathbf c_2 - \mathbf c_3 \Big)  $ does lie in the column space where $\mathbf c_1 \cdots \mathbf c_3 $ are the columns of the original matrix.

Comment: Regarding “... reduce ... by column operations if you want to determine the independence of the column vectors,” row-reduction preserves dependencies among the columns, so it in fact suffices for that. There might be another reason to prefer column-reduction for this problem, but that’s not it.

Comment: ... because then ... etc.